# memory layout of class hierarchy

Tags: c++, unions, memory-layout

My target is to create instances of classes of a class hierarchy which share some common data. I create ( with a union ) enough memory so that the biggest instance can be created at the allocated memory. Now I want to create / exchange the instance of the class and use the "old" data at the memory there. Is this a valid/legal operation?

The original code uses some MTP stuff to create the union and the target is to use this class hierarchy as a core of a state machine implementation. I only show the basic code here which contains the problem.

I saw that it is a problem if the base class did not contain virtual methods but the derived ones did. This is because the vtable-pointer goes in front of the memory ( with gcc on x86/linux).

Simple question: Can an instance of a derived class access data from the base class if the instance of the base class was created before and the memory is reused with the instance of that derived class?

```
class Base
{
    public:
        int a;
        Base()=default;
        Base( int _a):a(_a){}

        void Print() { cout << "Value: " << a << endl; }
};

class Derived1: public Base
{
    public:
        int d;

        Derived1(): d( 0x11223344){}
};

union  U
{   
    U(){}
    Base base;
    Derived1 derived1;
} u;

int main()
{
    memset( &u, 0, sizeof(u));

    new (&u) Base(12345678);
    u.base.Print();

    new (&u) Derived1;
    u.base.Print();
 }
```

Comment: This is a totally wrong approach when doing OOP. You should use a `Base*` pointer, and it can point to any derived class.

Comment: The question is not how to access the data via pointer or not. The question was if it is safe that the layout in a hierarchy is safe to use common data in a hierarchy. The original code should use the data inside the derived classes. The presented code is only to see the effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this won't work because the sandard says:

> **9.5/1 :** in a union, at most one of the non-static data members can be active at any time that is, the value of at most one of the
>   non-static data members can be stored in a union at any time.

What you try to do is undefined behaviour:

```
new (&u) Derived1;  // RISKY !!!
```

With the placement new you overwrite the object that was in u before, without destroying it correctly.  Then the creation of `Derived1` will anyway create its own base.  If somehow you manage to keep the old values in memory, it's still undefined behaviour: it could work or not,  depending on the object layout and implemetnation of your compiler.

Answer (score 0):

This is undefined behaviour - it might appear to work, but is not portable and should not be depended on.

A union can only have one active member; constructing the `Derived1` invalidates what went before.